# How to access the user from the request in the express get method

Tags: node.js, express

Assume that i am logged in my windows as a user "X", i am accessing a service "Y" from chrome, which is hosted using node express.

Whenever user access the "Y" service in the express, i need to get the user requesting the service.

How to access the user from the request in the node express get method.

```
const express = require("express");
//Express request pipeline
const  app = express();
app.get('/newq', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.user)
});
```

**undefined** is what i get as output.

How will i able to get the user of the request

Answer (score 0):

Express does not come with a `req.user` property. You have to use some kind of middleware in order to identify your user. Suggested way is to use [session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session).